# MKMapView compass visibility notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I would like to ask how should I notify if `MKMapView` is being rotated. 
I want to achieve that if Compass is shown, some buttons should change the position.

My first thought is that compass is shown, when I rotate map with two fingers then I want to change the location of buttons.

Is there any build-in method to check if map is rotating?

Something similar to `DidBeginEditing`?

Comment: You could try monitoring the camera’s rotation angle in `regionDidChange`

Comment: In connection with camera heading the answer is this what I was looking for. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) reference.

When you rotate map with two fingers, these methods be called:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Make sure your map view's delegate property is set so those methods get called.